# Spring Batch Partitioning At Runtime

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to read a large file using spring batch. I want to split into multiple files and process each of them in a different thread using partitions. I am using the below code:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner() {
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    partitioner.setKeyName("file");
    partitioner.setResources(splitFiles());
    return partitioner;
}

private Resource[] splitFiles() {
    // Read the large File available in the specified folder
    // split the file to smaller files and return them as resource list
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutorPartitionHandler partitionHandler() {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    partitionHandler.setStep(step1());
    partitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    return partitionHandler;
}

@Bean
public Step partitionedMaster() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .partitioner(step1().getName(), partitioner(null))
                .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
                .build();
}

@Bean
public Job partitionedJob() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("partitionedJob")
                                .start(partitionedMaster())
                                .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Transaction> fileTransactionReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['file']}") Resource resource) {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Transaction>()
                .name("flatFileTransactionReader")
                .resource(resource)
                .fieldSetMapper(fsm)
                .build();
}
```

My issue is that the partitioner is partitioning the files which are only available in the folder at the start of the application. Once the application is up and running, if a new file is available in the same folder, the job couldn't read them/partition them.
I used @StepScope, still i'm having the issue.

How do I read and partition the files dynamically at runtime?

> Editing it after the first answer:

Hi, Thanks for the inputs.
I can modify the code as below to send the files as parameters and invoke the job, but still the control is not going inside partitioner method, hence could not leverage partitioning.
Any inputs on this?

```
public JobParameters getJobParameters() {
    Resource[] resources = //getFileToProcessResource
    return new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong(TIME, System.currentTimeMillis())
            .addString("inputFiles", resources)
            .toJobParameters();
}

JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParameters();
jobLauncher.run(partitionedJob(), jobParameters);

@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputFiles']}") Resource[] resources) {
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    partitioner.setKeyName("file");
    partitioner.setResources(resources);
    return partitioner;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once the application is up and running, if a new file is available in the same folder, the job couldn't read them/partition them

Batch processing is about fixed data sets. In your case, you start a job but its input data changes in the meantime, so that's not going to work as you expect. A fixed data set is required for restartability in order to work on the same data set in case of failure.

Since the input of your job is a file, you can use the file as a job parameter and configure a watch service (or similar mechanism) to launch a new job instance for each new file in the folder.

EDIT: Add example to make the partitioner aware of the job parameter

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    partitioner.setKeyName("file");
    partitioner.setResources(splitFiles(fileName));
    return partitioner;
}

private Resource[] splitFiles(String fileName) {
    // Read the large File available in the specified folder
    // split the file to smaller files and return them as resource list
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the inputs. I can modify the code as below to send the files as parameters and invoke the job, but still the control is not going inside partitioner method, hence could not leverage partitioning. Any inputs on this?

Comment: Basically all I want to do is to read a large csv file from ftp daily and do some processing on the data and store in the database

Comment: I have done the exact same thing. But when the new job execution is triggered, I'm not seeing the method partitionedJob() or partitioner() being invoked. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found my issue. Code is right. Just that it need to be part of Configuration.